# Athena Timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, amazon-athena, presto, trino

What is the appropriate format for my datetime?  I've tried several combinations and getting various errors.  The data is a string and here is an example: "2022-10-28T00:00:00Z"

Neither of these work:

`WHERE MONTH(parse_datetime(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH:mm:ss"Z"')) = 12

`WHERE MONTH(parse_datetime(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) = 12

[image]

Comment: Show us your `parse_datetime` method.

Comment: What programming language? Straight SQL? Or SQL embedded in a language like Java?

Comment: @BasilBourque Amazon Athena is based on Presto/Trino SQL engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes (`'`) to escape symbol when using [Java date functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions). To add it to the format string you need to escape it with another one:

```sql
select parse_datetime('2023-01-30T20:00:02Z', 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss''Z''');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2023-01-30 20:00:02.000 UTC |

Note that in this case you can just use [`from_iso8601_timestamp`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp) function, which should be more correct approach in general:

```sql
select from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-01-30T20:00:02Z');
```

Comment: Incorrect. Never put quotes around the `Z`. Doing so tells the formatter to expect, but ignore, the letter’s presence. Don’t ignore that the date and time are intended to have an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. You are discarding vital information. See [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: @BasilBourque yep, I was working on the updating the answer.